# Google App Engine PHP, Couldn't resolve host

Tags: google-app-engine, google-php-sdk

Tonight we started getting curl errors with Google App Engine involved in resolving hostnames that are many including google.

Error: "Couldn't resolve host 'maps.google.com'" - Code: 6

Yes, Billing is enabled, and this has been working for months until just now.
Thought I would post to see if anyone knew anything.

This issue persists both when having the cURL extension (which uses Sockets service) enabled, as well as cURL lite (which uses URL Fetch service) enabled.

Google App Engine PHP5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Google fixed it even though they never admit but it works now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that Google has fixed this issue. After experiencing the same issue for the last 20+ hours, now all is working fine.