# Google Pub/Sub error on AppEngine "Couldn't resolve host 'pubsub.googleapis.com"

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

Everything was working until this morning...

I am getting the error:

> 'cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host 'pubsub.googleapis.com'

when trying to send messages to a pubsub topic.

We are running on AppEngine

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the same issue reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478889/google-app-engine-php-couldnt-resolve-host) and now seems to be resolved.